# Add class to last div when it exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure, I want to add a class to the last `<div>` which contains the `<p>` tag but only when it exists.

```
<div id="view">
  <div class="login">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Add a class to this parent DIV</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `$("> div:last:has('p')", "#view").addClass('class')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple snippet:

```
if($('#view div:last p').​​​​​​​​​​​length)
    $('#view div:last').addClass('myClass');​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score -1):

Will get all the divs that has a p tag

```
p = $('#view div p');
if (p.length) {
  $(p[p.length - 1]).addClass("largerText");
}​
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLLWg/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes Roaster given right answer and this is the fiddle for it. http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/qhsXM/

```
<div id="view">
  <div class="login">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Add a class to this parent DIV</p>
  </div>
</div>​

if($('#view div:last p').length){
    $('#view div:last').addClass('myClass');
}
​
.myClass {
    border:red 1px solid;
}​
```